# I tried to make a window using GLUT to use OpenGL, but it gave me errors I didn't understand

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glut

I just started using Graphics Library Utility Toolkit, and Open Graphics Library (GLUT+OpenGL).

I wanted to create a window and I tried this code using various tutorials, but it didn't work.

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
void display(void) {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glFlush();
}   

int main (int argc, char **argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("My First GLUT/OpenGL Window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

It gave me the error:

> cannot convert '`char***`' to '`char**`' for argument '`2`' to '`void glutInit(int*, char**)`'"

It gave me the error at line 13.

Could anybody please give me some information on this? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! The first choice worked.

Comment: But sorry for asking, what is the difference?

Comment: @Mat: Don't post answers as comments

Comment: @BitLion: The difference is, that what you asked the compiler to generate for the second argument of main would be "a pointer to a pointer to a array(=pointer) to char". That's one pointer too much. Also this violates the requirements on the main function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're passing a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-char as a second argument to `glutInit`. That's not what that function expects, it takes a pointer-to-pointer-to-char.

The problem comes from your signature for `main`. The standard two-argument `main` function takes an int and a pointer-to-pointer-to-char.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Which can also be written:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

(The two forms are equivalent.)

You're adding one more indirection level.

Comment: I'm looking into pointers right now, thank you for your help!